# getting "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber compare:]: nil argument'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Though we have lot of people asked same question , none of the answers are helping to fix my issue. So here is my code ,

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", text);



    //The NSJSONSerialization method to transform the NSData responseObject into a dictionnary does work
    NSJSONSerialization *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];

    //This NSLog makes the app crash with an unrecognized selector sent error
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@",jsonResponse);

    NSArray *result1=(NSArray *)[jsonResponse valueForKeyPath:@"result"];

    NSLog(@"result1: %@",result1);

    NSMutableString  *shipPrice =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    NSMutableString  *freeLimitString =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    if(result1!=Nil && ![result1 count]==0)
    {
               for (int i=0; i<result1.count; i++)
               {
                    NSNumber *totalShippingPrice = [[result1  objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"totalShippingPrice"];
                    if( totalShippingPrice != nil && totalShippingPrice && [totalShippingPrice isEqualToNumber:0]&& [totalShippingPrice intValue]==0) // ISSUE LINE
                                {
                                    shipPrice = (NSMutableString*)@"FREE";
                                } } } }
```

I kept breakpoint and exactly its happening in this above line. Im new to `AFNetworking`. Im not sure how to fix it. Help me with working code sample :) Thanks

Comment: Casting `@"FREE"` to `(NSMutableString*)` will result in an error if you later try to modify (mutate) `shipPrice`. You should use `[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"FREE"]` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
[totalShippingPrice isEqualToNumber: [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]
```

In the line that crashes.
You need to compare the object with another one of the same type, if you use 0 is the same as if you were sending nil to it, so you need to create a NSNumber as I wrote.

Or just do:

```
[totalShippingPrice intValue] == 0
```

Comment: With modern Objective-C you can do `[totalShippingPrice isEqualToNumber: @(0)]`.

Comment: When i try above Antonio's solution , im getting 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendFormat:'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3294a3e7 0x3a63b963 0x3294a307 0x329199e3 0x328df685 0x42713f 0x4d8ecf 0x3aa55793 0x3aa555db 0x3aa58e45 0x3291e1b1 0x3289123d 0x328910c9 0x3646f33b 0x347ad2b9 0xd7809 0x3aa68b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: I guess it's this one `(NSMutableString*)@"FREE";`... you can't just cast an immutable string to mutable and expect it to work...

Comment: +1 Yes Antonio , Same Line. I just removed "totalShippingPrice != nil" and Rerun with your suggested code alone. It worked. Thank you... :) for both.

Comment: Alladinian so far that line not causing any issue. Will check in future :). Anyway thanks.

Comment: @Meenu It _will_ cause if you try to call an `NSMutableString` method to it. Convert to `[@"Free" mutableCopy]`

Comment: @ThomasW Or even more concise: `@0`. (Also works with `@YES`)